# C# clear selectbox and build it dynamically - Windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, drop-down-menu

How to clear all the options in a select box in C# (Windows form application)?
Is there something easy or does the code need to loop over all the items?

How to dynamically add an option to this select box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

call the `Clear()` method on the `Items` Property

```
listControl.Items.Clear();
```

This will work for a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) or a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Windows Forms ListBox control you can use ListBox.Items.Clear()

Comment: its not its regular selectbox